# First Pyspark Program

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, log4j

i'm having trouble running my first Pyspark program.
i'm running this code on jypyter notebook which i configured to use instead of the shell

```
import sys
from pyspark import SparkContext

lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
word_counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(' '))\
                   .map(lambda word: (word,1)) \
                   .reduceByKey(lambda count1, count2: count1 + count2) \
                   .collect()

for (word,count) in woord_counts:
    print(word,count)
```

and i'm getting this error:

```
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-727078dac5d6> in <module>()
      5 sc
      6 lines = sc.textFile(sys.argv[1])
----> 7 word_counts = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(' '))                   .map(lambda word: (word,1))                    .reduceByKey(lambda count1, count2: count1 + count2)                    .collect()
      8 
      9 for (word,count) in word_counts:

/home/mouad/code/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in reduceByKey(self, func, numPartitions, partitionFunc)
   1696         [('a', 2), ('b', 1)]
   1697         """
-> 1698         return self.combineByKey(lambda x: x, func, func, numPartitions, partitionFunc)
   1699 
   1700     def reduceByKeyLocally(self, func):

/home/mouad/code/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in combineByKey(self, createCombiner, mergeValue, mergeCombiners, numPartitions, partitionFunc)
   1923         """
   1924         if numPartitions is None:
-> 1925             numPartitions = self._defaultReducePartitions()
   1926 
   1927         serializer = self.ctx.serializer
```

coudln't paste the whole error code , so i'll do that in the next comments..

i tried running this script through spark-submit but i get the following error :

```
hduser_@Master:/home/mouad/code/spark/bin$ ./spark-submit ./wordcount.py ./test.txt
20/03/13 10:26:50 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Error executing Jupyter command '/home/mouad/code/spark/bin/./wordcount.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.apache.spark.util.ShutdownHookManager).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

Can anyone help me get through this?

Comment: 2nd part of the error code
`
/home/mouad/code/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in _defaultReducePartitions(self)
   2333             return self.ctx.defaultParallelism
   2334         else:
-> 2335             return self.getNumPartitions()
   2336 
   2337     def lookup(self, key):

/home/mouad/code/spark/python/pyspark/rdd.py in getNumPartitions(self)
   2599 
   2600     def getNumPartitions(self):
-> 2601         return self._prev_jrdd.partitions().size()
   2602 
   2603     @property

`

Comment: 3rd part of the error code 
`/home/mouad/code/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py in __call__(self, *args)
   1284         answer = self.gateway_client.send_command(command)
   1285         return_value = get_return_value(
-> 1286             answer, self.gateway_client, self.target_id, self.name)
   1287 
   1288         for temp_arg in temp_args:

`

Comment: 4th part :

`/home/mouad/code/spark/python/pyspark/sql/utils.py in deco(*a, **kw)
     96     def deco(*a, **kw):
     97         try:
---> 98             return f(*a, **kw)
     99         except py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError as e:
    100             converted = convert_exception(e.java_exception)
`

Comment: 5th part :

/home/mouad/code/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.8.1-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    326                 raise Py4JJavaError(
    327                     "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
--> 328                     format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329             else:
    330                 raise Py4JError(

Comment: 6th part : 
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o35.partitions.
: org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/mouad/code/spark/-f
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.singleThreadedListStatus(FileInputFormat.java:297)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:239)
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:325)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.HadoopRDD.getPartitions(HadoopRDD.scala:205)
 at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.$anonfun$partitions$2(RDD.scala:276)

Comment: and it goes on and on it's more to it ...i can't paste the whole error code 
these are the last lines 
 at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
 at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
 at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
 at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
 at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

Answer (score 0):

I noticed you are giving the file path as relative using `./test.txt` , please give the full file path using the `file:///<full-path-of-file>` notation also of you are running it on a cluster , kindly make sure that the file you are trying to read is available at the same location across all nodes in your cluster .

Answer (score 0):

If you have configured the Jupyter Notebook for running your Pyspark Applications you don't need to use `sys.argv[1]` in your code for passing the location of your file, rather you should pass the full path of your file.

If you spark master and slave nodes are running properly, you can try executing the below code.

```
from operator import add
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession

spark = (
    SparkSession.builder.appName("WordCountApp")
    .master("local[*]")
    .getOrCreate()
)
sqlcontext = SQLContext(spark)

lines  = spark.read.text("wordcount.txt").rdd.map(lambda r: r[0])
counts = lines.flatMap(lambda x: x.split(' ')) \
              .map(lambda x: (x, 1)) \
              .reduceByKey(add)

output = counts.collect()
for (word, count) in output:
    print("%s: %i" % (word, count))
```